# Creak source suggestions

Tags: drivetrain, creak

I have a creak from my carbon frameset Cervelo R3SL with full 1osp Duraace groupset and external hollowtec II BB.  I have isolated it to drivetrain as creaks when out of saddle or none handed.  I've stripped crankset down and reassembled. Creak is not in any particular time wrt to crank, wheel or chain rotation.  It is quiet to start and creaks after say 10 miles, quietening again later. Perhaps this is some friction that warms grease or such like.  The crankset is 10 years old and on its 2nd big ring. I have noticed that the axle has suffered some minor corrosion on the bearing surfaces. I've cleaned this up with 1000 grit.  But I am wondering if the issue is connected.  Wheels are pretty new, so I'd be surprised if that was the issue.  Otherwise it is flawless.  Any ideas?

Comment: Did you apply any lube to the crank axle during reassembly? Try it on both the bearing to axle mating surface and the crankarm. Do one, then the other so you only have a single variable.

Comment: Do you have access to rollers ? I have found that tracking down creaks is hard while riding, and having a helper's ear off to one side can work much better.

Comment: yes, i use a dab of grease on the surfaces. I don't have rollers presently. I'll get to the bottom of it I'm sure, just wondered if anyone has any bright ideas.  Thx

Comment: I recently went through this on my bike.  Replacing the bottom bracket (a threaded BB, not press-fit) eliminated some of the creak.  Rebuilding the pedals got the rest.  I was a little surprised, as it seemed like all the creaking started at once.  So it goes.